# Pairwise Comparisons for Rank Based rfit Models in emmeans

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, robust, lsmeans

I recently found this package: https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2012-2/RJournal_2012-2_Kloke+McKean.pdf. I am utilizing this package for Robust Regression without having to resort to M or MM-estimation methods which have a weakness of downweighting more points than necessary as well as convergence problems in the IRLS algorithm.

This package performs a rank regression based on minimizing some rank based pseudo norm. While the pdf mentions multiple comparisons, I am not able to do those through rfit for K-way ANOVAs.

I want to try to use the emmeans package (which is my usual go-to for contrasts) to obtain pairwise comparisons but it seems this model is not supported. I tried following https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/xtending.html but the problem is the rfit object does not have a "terms" component. Thus I cannot use the recover_data.lm method on it.

Is there any way at all to use the emmeans package with an rfit object? Or any way I can perform multiple corrected pairwise comparisons?

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually have something with regression coefficients, or is it all oriented towards hypothesis tests? If the latter, there may not be much hope. But if the former, look at the `qdrg()` function and it’d help page.

Comment: Oops I meant “... and its help page.”

Comment: @rvl Thanks a lot! With rfit() instead of the raov() function you do indeed get something with the usual regression coefficients. Unfortunately, you cannot do anova() on this but it looks like the qdrg() function from emmeans works to get the pairwise contrasts. Seems like it defaults to a Wald Z Test, which is fine as the rfit() summary  also seems to use a Wald Test. All I had to do for qdrg() to work was provide the data frame object. Much easier than the extending emmeans method I was trying before.

Comment: I'm glad it works. I'm adding more pointers to `qdrg()` in the package documentation so that future users are more likely to find it.

Comment: @rvl Is there a way to use `qdrg()` with mixed models? I am also investigating robust mixed model methods (such as those in robustlmm or rlme). These models have a similar summary() as lmer() or nlme(). I believe internally they also use nlme(). I tried qdrg() on these objects but it didn't seem to work. I also tried it with the standard lmer() (just as a check) but ran into problems. Got some error about rank deficiency though using `emmeans()` on the `lmer()` object worked fine.

Comment: It may work if you skip the `object` argument and specify the fixed-effects formula, coefficients, etc individually